PNPM Cannot create files. ERR_PNPM_ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory
I am trying to run pnpm install for a public project chainlit but get ERR_PNPM_ENOENT. pnpm version is 9.0.6. pnpm doctor outputs nothing. I tried clearing the cache but the error still persists:
 ERR_PNPM_ENOENT  ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/home/vscode/Developer/.pnpm-store/v3/files/a8/19920fe80efddfaf1ca87f65664b25fbe85068659103d1a30b48182cb1c8807276b1bfbfbd07176558c89b09eca71438298814a8280c89515924fd740e0000' -> '/home/vscode/Developer/chainlit/libs/react-client/node_modules/fastq_tmp_48220/.github/workflows/ci.yml'

The file exists in .pnpm store and I am also able to cat out the contents.
~/Developer/chainlit (main) $ ls /home/vscode/Developer/.pnpm-store/v3/files/a8/19920fe80efddfaf1ca87f65664b25fbe85068659103d1a30b48182cb1c8807276b1bfbfbd07176558c89b09eca71438298814a8280c89515924fd740e0000
/home/vscode/Developer/.pnpm-store/v3/files/a8/19920fe80efddfaf1ca87f65664b25fbe85068659103d1a30b48182cb1c8807276b1bfbfbd07176558c89b09eca71438298814a8280c89515924fd740e0000

However, the second file does not exist.
~/Developer/chainlit (main) $ ls /home/vscode/Developer/chainlit/libs/react-client/node_modules/fastq_tmp_48220/.github/workflows/ci.yml
ls: cannot access '/home/vscode/Developer/chainlit/libs/react-client/node_modules/fastq_tmp_48220/.github/workflows/ci.yml': No such file or directory

Also, it is a different error each time. Re running pnpm install another time gives:
 ERR_PNPM_ENOENT  ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/home/vscode/Developer/.pnpm-store/v3/files/cf/83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e' -> '/home/vscode/Developer/chainlit/frontend/node_modules/resolve_tmp_54639/test/resolver/browser_field/b.js'

I think pnpm is having issues in creating the file in the project node_modules. I turned off linking with node-linker=hoisted in the .npmrc.
This is running in a vscode devcontainer, where ~/Developer on the local filesystem is mounted to /home/vscode/Developer in the container.
 "mounts": [
        // mount $HOME/Developer to ~/Developer
        "source=${localEnv:HOME}${localEnv:USERPROFILE}/Developer,target=/home/vscode/Developer,type=bind,consistency=consistent",
    ],

The pnpm store is on the local filesystem too and set with: pnpm config set store-path /home/vscode/Developer/.pnpm-store .
I confirmed permissions on Developer in the container
~/Developer/chainlit (main) $ ls -la ~ | grep "Developer"
drwxr-xr-x 17 vscode vscode  544 Apr 30 00:10 Developer

I turned off linking with node-linker=hoisted in the .npmrc. pnpm doctor` outputs nothing. I tried clearing the cache.
